# How to copy the last non-blank cell in a column that contains blank cells with formulas in them

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to copy the last cell with value in a column (it is a formula that returns a value). The only problem is that after the last value in a specific column, there are more formulas that return a blank value.

When I use this code :

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
Cells(LastRow, "C").Copy
```

it copies the last cell that contains a formula so it copies a blank cell.. I want it to copy the last cell that shows a value.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: To clarify, the cell has a formula in it, but the formula is returning a blank. You want to then keep going up rows (so from row 20, to 19 to 18 etc) until the formula returns a non blank value. Then you want to copy **that** formula down?

Comment: Yes exactly! I want to copy the last cell of the column that returns a value

Comment: Thinking about this -- Is the formula the same in all rows? Or to be super clear, do you want to copy the *value* and not the *formula* down 30 rows?

Comment: The formula is the same in all the rows of a column, but different in each column. I want to copy the formula not the value. Would this work?    :     SpecialCells(Type:=xlCellTypeConstants, Value:=xlTextValues)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you'd be looking for (also incorporating code from your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57316856/how-to-drag-formulas-in-a-loop-on-multiple-worksheets/57317005#57317005) question):

```
For col = 1 To lastCol
    If .Cells(1, col).Value = "F" Then
        'lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row
        lastRow = .Columns(col).Find("*", SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
        .Range(.Cells(lastRow, col), .Cells(lastRow + copyRowAmt, col)).Formula = _
            .Cells(lastRow, col).Formula
    End If
Next col
```

Comment: Wonderful! It works perfectly! Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SpecialCells` feature of Range Class in this case. A bit tricky but will do the Job efficiently.

**Try:**

```
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).row
LastRow = Split(Range("C1:C" & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Address, "$")(4)
Cells(LastRow, "C").Copy
```

---

**Updated:**

```
For c = 1 To 20

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).row
    LastRow = Split(Range(Cells(1, c), Cells(LastRow, c)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Address, "$")(4)
    Cells(LastRow, c).Copy

Next c
```

Answer (score 0):

@Mikku - Thank you for the answer! The only thing now is that I am looping through columns in a worksheet. My code really is :

```
For c = 1 To 20
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, c).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRow = Split(Range(c & LastRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Address, "$")(4)
    Cells(LastRow, c).Copy

Next c
```

So how would I insert your code in my loop?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the last row a true "value", or a formula that results in a value and not a blank?

Comment: The last row is a formula that returns a blank and the last "value" is also a formula that results in a value.

Comment: @TristB , use the Updated Answer

Comment: Then the `xlCellTypeConstants` approach won't work, because you're dealing with a *formula*.

Comment: Oh.. but is it possible to return only the last cell with a formula that results in a value and not a blank?

Comment: Yes but you'll need a different approach.

Comment: @Mikku - thank you! Unfortunatly as BigBen said, I forgot to mention that the last value I want to copy is the result of a formula..

Comment: FYI `Range(c & lastRow)` isn't a valid construction. You likely want to split `Cells(lastRow, c)...`